# Nested KML downloads as opposed to displays

Tags: javascript, google-maps, kml

I would like to incorporate the following kmz file: http://www.cru.uea.ac.uk/cru/data/crutem/ge/CRUTEM4-2013-03_gridboxes_grey.kml produced by the Climatic Research Unit, University East Anglia in my Google map using Google Map JS API.

When this file is viewed using Google Earth, you get a checkerboard.  Click on a grid and you get an info window with a link "stations". If you click on the link to stations (which points to another kml file), the weather stations within the grid are displayed. Clicking on any of them gives you the annual temp plus variations.

I have managed to display the same overlay on my map but clicking on the link "stations" results in a file download of the kml as opposed to displaying the contents of the kml within the Google map.

The code is as follows:

```
createCRUTEMlayer('http://www.cru.uea.ac.uk/cru/data/crutem/ge/CRUTEM4-2013-03_gridboxes_grey.kml');


function createCRUTEMlayer(myURL) {

     CRUTEMset = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
        url: myURL,
        preserveViewport: true
     });

     // the following check on status has been placed within a listener on status change as it is not available right away

     google.maps.event.addListener(CRUTEMset,'status_changed',function(){
        if (CRUTEMset.getStatus() != 'OK') {
           alert('Google Maps could not load the layer: ' + myURL + ' Status returned is: ' + CRUTEMset.getStatus());
        }
     });

     CRUTEMset.setMap(map);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've no idea how to *nicely* solve this. But peeking into the generated HTML, one sees the following for the "Stations" link in the popup:

```
<div class="gm-style-iw" ...>
    ...
    <a href="http://www.cru.uea.ac.uk/cru/..._stations.kml" ...>Stations</a>
```

One could use some jQuery trickery to get the new URL from those links when clicked, and load a new layer using that:

```
// Handle any link that ends in .kml ourselves:
$("body").on("click", "a[href$='.kml']", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var newURL = $(this).attr("href");
    createCRUTEMlayer(newURL);
});
```

This adds the Station markers (and their popups), but does not remove them until the page is refreshed. I don't know enough of these layers to remove them when clicking somewhere else, but I'm sure it's doable.

Beware that this is a dangerous hack as the contents of the third party KML file can change. If, for example, the links in the KML no longer end with `.kml`, then the jQuery selector won't find them anymore. Also, this handles *all* links that end in `.kml`. One could limit jQuery to the Google Maps info box using `on("click", ".gm-style-iw a[href$='.kml']", ...` but that would introduce a dependency on the Google Maps HTML.

Full snippet below.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>KML Layers</title>
    <style>
      html, body, #map-canvas {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px
      }
    </style>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp"></script>
    <!-- jQuery 1.x for support IE8 and older -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>

// Global, not too nice, but allowing for using the function from the question.
var map;

function createCRUTEMlayer(myURL) {

     CRUTEMset = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
        url: myURL,
        preserveViewport: true
     });

     // the following check on status has been placed within a listener on status change as it is not available right away

     google.maps.event.addListener(CRUTEMset,'status_changed',function(){
        if (CRUTEMset.getStatus() != 'OK') {
           alert('Google Maps could not load the layer: ' + myURL + ' Status returned is: ' + CRUTEMset.getStatus());
        }
     });

     CRUTEMset.setMap(map);
}

function initialize() {
    var amsterdam = new google.maps.LatLng(52.370215,4.895167);
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 3,
        center: amsterdam,
        preserveViewport: true
    }

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

    createCRUTEMlayer('http://www.cru.uea.ac.uk/cru/data/crutem/ge/CRUTEM4-2013-03_gridboxes_grey.kml');

    // Handle any link that ends in .kml ourselves:
    $("#map-canvas").on("click", "a[href$='.kml']", function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var newURL = $( this ).attr("href");
        createCRUTEMlayer(newURL);

        // Click the next div after the popup's main <div>, being the close button...
        $(this).parents(".gm-style-iw").next().click();
    });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```